# AJAX error from Entity Browser modal: "The container is serialized." What does that mean?

Tags: 8, entities, media

When I use Entity Browser, and I edit a media field... lets say its an image - when I click on "remove" and upload a new image, nothing happens. There is a JS 
 AJAX error in the console that says:

"The container is serialized."

The modal is then stuck and goes nowhere - but the file operation still occurred in the background (refreshing the page displays this behavior).

[image: AJAX error]

I have seen this mentioned a few times, some people say to use `DependencySerializationTrait` - why? What does this error mean exactly?